# Delay before a specific action in OnTriggerStay()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, delay

I'm making a 3d-shooter in Unity. I want to let player nail up windows and doors so that he had a cover. Holes in the walls like windows and doors already have inactive boards on them. I'd like to have the player hold the button when he's near the window to set a board active. So, if it is required to nail down three boards to completly shut up the window, the player has to be near the window and hold a button, for instance, for 10 seconds to place one board. Same for the second and third boards. This process, however, can be interrupted and the window can have only one or two boards nailed down. Windows have invisible triggers that detect player's presence.

Here's the code attached to windows:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ActivateBoards : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float delay = 10f;
    public List<GameObject> boards;
    private int currentAmount = 0;
    private int totalAmount;
    private float elapsed = 0f;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        totalAmount = boards.Count;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player") && Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1") && currentAmount != totalAmount)
        {
            elapsed += Time.deltaTime;
            if (elapsed >= delay)
            {
                boards[currentAmount].SetActive(true);
                currentAmount++;
                elapsed = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to use a coroutine but it's a no go since the player can release the button right in the middle of `yield return new WaitForSeconds()` command. Also, I'd like to attach a UI image that would play a role of a progress bar and fill up as time goes by. I don't really get along with time in Unity - the code above doesn't work at all. And I suppose that `Time.deltaTime` only works well in `Update()` method? I need fuctionality from `OnTriggerStay()` to detect player and functionality from `Update()` to count time. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main issue I'ld say is that your are using `GetButtonDown` which is only true exactly **one** frame per button press.

You should rather use `GetButton` which is `true` **every frame** as long the button stays pressed!

```
private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
{
    if (!other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player") return;

    // instead of totalAmount you could directly use the boards.Length (or .Count for a List)
    // I would also rather check for < instead of !=
    if(Input.GetButton("Fire1") && currentAmount < boards.Length)
    {
        elapsed += Time.deltaTime;
        if (elapsed >= delay)
        {
            boards[currentAmount].SetActive(true);
            currentAmount++;
            elapsed = 0;
        }
    }
    else if (Input.GetButtonUp("Fire1"))
    {
        // Button was released
        elapsed = 0;
    }
}

// I would then also reset if player leaves the collider
private void OnTriggerExit (Collider other)
{
    if (!other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player") return;

    elapsed = 0;
}
```

Comment: it works, and it's so simple! Many thanks! I can't believe it was that easy. But isn't it better to store `boards.Count` value in a variable since the length of the list is constant and hence we will re-calculate the same value every time which is a bit wastefully?

Comment: `boards.Count` isn't recalculated ;) The list already knows its length. If you are sure you can ofcourse store it at the beginning and then access it this way .. I just thought you might being setting it via the Inspector which you should not, definitely get it from the list to be more flexible when e.g. switching to 2 or 5 boards without forgetting to update also that value ;)

Comment: ooh, I see, it's not a method which's called but a property of the list. Got it, much obliged

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem in a game I'm currently making. The way I went about solving it was actually creating a progress bar that is hidden during normal play (disabled) and then brought back when needed. How I achieved a progress bar was by using a slider and disabling the interactable bit of it. Then by changing the value of the slider from code I was able to achieve an effect of a progress bar. The code I wrote for it is down below if you want to try and use it yourself.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class InterationMeter_Controller : MonoBehaviour
{
    GameManager GameManager;
    Slider Slider;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        //Ref to GameManager, (Tagged "GameController")
        GameManager = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GameController").GetComponent<GameManager>();
        Slider = gameObject.GetComponent<Slider>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Slider.value -= Time.deltaTime; //Counts down in rl seconds
        if (Slider.value <= 0) 
        {
            GameManager.UIManager.gameObject.SendMessage("OnInteractionMeterFinish");  //Call the UIManager to let it know the timer is done
        }
    }
}
```

Basically the premise is that when I want to trigger some sort of timer-based interaction. I call my UI manager and tell it to run the progress bar for x seconds by setting the value of the slider. I then have a receiver method in my UI manager that is called if the progress bar finishes. If I need to stop the bar midway, I can just tell the UI manager to hide the progress bar which stops the Update method from being called. This effectively resets the timer since I reset the time before I call it on screen again.

How I think you could use this is by having the OnTriggerStay() allow an interact button of sorts to be pressed. You could then call your version of a UI Manager to start this timer and when you need to stop the timer, just call it again.

Comment: Thanks for help! I tried your solution and it worked. However, I later swap it for derHugo's solution, as I think it's a bit more elegant. No offense, you also helped me a lot! I upvoted your post, hope it's all right :)

Comment: @AlexeyBogdan Yeah no problem, I see that you just wanted the timer to run while a button was pushed.